# ¿Cómo puedo evitar que se repita un número random en una serie de números?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, random

Estoy creando un programa especie de lotería power ball o mega million con el módulo **random-number** de **NodeJS**, donde lanzo cinco números y una bola usando el ciclo for. El problema es que los números se han llegado a repetir hasta 2 veces en un mismo lanzamiento y quiero evitar eso pero no se me ocurre ninguna idea. Este es mi código:

```
const rn = require('random-number');
var options = {
    min: 1,
    max: 60,
    integer: true
}

var balls = {
    min: 1,
    max: 30,
    integer: true
}
var ball;
var n1,n2,n3,n4,n5;
var count = [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5]
var c = 1;


for(var i in count) {
    count[i] = rn(options)

    console.log("Number " + c + ": " + count[i])
    c++;
}
ball = rn(balls)
console.log("Ball: "+ball)
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando parte de tu código pude hacer lo que tu pides, lo cual es no repetir un número random. Para emular tu libreria **random-number** utilice **Math.random()** para generar número aleatorios y lo puse a solo buscar aleatorios del 1 al 10 con:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
```

Lo unico que hice fue utilizar **indexOf** para determinar si el valor ya existe en dicho arreglo, de no existir lo asigno al array:

```js
var n1,n2,n3,n4,n5;
var count = [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5];

for(var i in count) {
  var aleatorio = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
  console.log("Numero aleatorio "+aleatorio);
  if(count.indexOf(aleatorio) === -1){
    count[i] = aleatorio;
  }
  
}
console.log(count);
```

Si en el array te salen valores **"undefined"** es porque intento insertar un valor ya existente en el array, lo deje así para que comprobaras que no repite los valores, pero tu puedes llamar una función donde la llames si el valor es repetido y busque una nuevo. Espero te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

Podrias evitar que lo agrege si ya lo contiene con el metodo

```
count.contains(ElNumeroRandom);
```

podria quedar así pero no lo he probado, dime si te funciona, aunque no es optimo resolvera tu problema, te recomiendo que pienses una logica diferente :)

```
const rn = require('random-number');
var options = {
    min: 1,
    max: 60,
    integer: true
}

var balls = {
    min: 1,
    max: 30,
    integer: true
}
var ball;
var n1,n2,n3,n4,n5;
var count = [n1,n2,n3,n4,n5]
var c = 1;

for(var i in count) {
    var aleatorio = rn(options)
    if(!count.contains(aleatorio)){
      count[i] = aleatorio;
      console.log("Number " + c + ": " + count[i])
      c++;  
    }
}
ball = rn(balls)
console.log("Ball: "+ball)
```

Comment: Hola, me sale un error que dice: Cannot read property 'contains' of undefined

Comment: `contains` no es una función de las clases base de JavaScript, tal vez la tienes por alguna librería.  La función que sí existe es `includes` y está disponible en la mayoría de navegadores.